# ¿Como cambiar puertos de mysql?

Tags: mysql

En esta ocasión tengo el problema de que quisiera cambiar el puerto de mysql (que por defecto viene en 3306), he visto en este video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9nl0_vEQcGI)que explica se puede hacer cambiando el puerto descrito en el archivo my.ini con el block de notas. Siguiendo las instrucciones, borro el 3306 y escribo el 3310 (por ejemplo), reinicio el servicio y luego abro el xaamp para iniciar el MySQL lo que termina

**Error: MySQL shutdown unexpectedly.
This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
Press the Logs button to view error logs and check the Windows Event Viewer for more clues
If you need more help, copy and post this entire log window on the forums**

Y no ejecuta. Finalmente para añadir, si regreso todo al puerto 3306 vuelve a funcionar.

Entonces realmente como debo hacer para cambiar el puerto al que yo quiera?

Muchas gracias

Edito:

Hice el mismo ejercicio pero escogiendo un puerto diferente y si funciono.
Tengo otra pregunta:
¿Es recomendable cambiar los puertos del apache y del mysql? Es que siento que al ser por defecto, todos los conocen y soy un blanco facil para hackear jajajaja

Comment: Estimado,
Prueba con este link: https://www.jsolucioncreativa.com/disenoweb-internet/cambiar-los-puertos-de-apache-y-mysql-en-xampp-correctamente/

Answer (score 1):

Estimado, para cambiar las configuracion en el Xampp debes de tener encuenta:

- Ejecutar el Panel de administracion de Xampp como administrador
- Si los tienes instalado el MySQL y Apache como servicio debes de reiniciarlos desde el **services.msc**
- Desactiva el firewall de windows.

Y probarlos nuevamente.